# First Four Words of Every Sentence, but Must Start With Word X and End With Word Y

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to filter the first four words of every sentence, with the first word being "This" and last word being "on." I've been trying to watch YouTube tutorials, but all I could do was the following:

```
([A-Z](?:[^\s.!?]+(?:\s|\n)){0,4}(?:[^\s.!?]+)?)
```

Now, here is an example: This [perception rests] on...

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I refrained from using x, thinking that would indicate I am referencing numbers. In my case, the blank words are "This" and "on."

Comment: What platform/tool/language are you using this with? There are many wrinkles on regex

Comment: I appreciate your patience with me. I am using the site: https://regexr.com/, which is Javascript.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "last word"? Are you trying to match "This [word] [word] on ..." or "This [word] [word] [word] .... on." ?

Comment: Sure thing. "This [word] [word] on" is what I want to match.

Comment: Yup, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?:^|[.;!?]\s+)(\bThis\W*?(\b\w+\b)\W*?(\b\w+\b)\W*on\b)
```

Would something like that work. As far as I understand you want the sentence to have four words, start with "This" and end on "on".

Comment: Two potential issues with this regex are that the sentence may not be at the start of the string and it will match "onto" as the fourth word.

Comment: Thank you so much your time. This, unfortunately, does not work exactly as I had hoped. It seems that this is only capable of successfully capturing the first instance of "This perception rests on."

Comment: Modified to capture all instances of This [] [] on and to capture "on" explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic regex would be

```
/\bThis\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+on\b/
```

which will match with no capturing. Perhaps what you consider a "word" character may differ from what the regex engine considers a word character.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using some NLP package to split text into sentences. Then use

```
^This\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+on\b
```

It matches a string that starts wth `This`, then has two words containing any non-whitespaces characters and then the word `on`.

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/6uYZwO/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  This                     'This'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  on                       'on'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```